# Singleton types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, dependent-type, type-theory, singleton-type

As part of doing a survey on various dependently typed formalization techniques, I have ran across a paper advocating the use of singleton types (types with one inhabitant) as a way of supporting dependently typed programming.

Acording to this source, in Haskell, there is a separation betwen runtime values and compile-time types that can be blurred when using singleton types, due to the induced type/value isomorphism.

My question is: How do singleton types differ from type-classes or from quoted/reified structures in this respect?

I would also particularly appreciate some intuitive explaination with respect to the type-theoretical importance/advantages to using singleton types and to the extent to which they can emulate dependent types in general.

Comment: Maybe the `singleton` tag should be removed?  It seems OOP-focused, and I don't think answers to this question will be relevant to that topic.

Comment: Ok, I fixed that. Thanks for the warning. I'll pay more attention next time that the tags are consistent with the meaning I have in mind.

Comment: One (theoretical) use of singleton types is to enable a simple proof technique for certain consequences of parametricity ("theorems for free"). See http://www.cs.cornell.edu/talc/papers/param-abstract.html

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As you describe, singleton types are those which have only one value (let's ignore `⊥` for the moment). Thus, the value of a singleton type has a unique type representing the value.  The crux of dependent-type theory (DTT) is that types can depend on values (or, said another way, values can parameterise types). A type theory that allows types to depend on types can use singleton types to let types depend on singleton values. In contrast, type classes provide *ad hoc polymorphism*, where values can depend on types (the other way round to DTT where types depend on values).

A useful technique in Haskell is to define a class of related singleton types. The classic example is of natural numbers:

```
data S n = Succ n 
data Z = Zero

class Nat n 
instance Nat Z
instance Nat n => Nat (S n)
```

Provided further instances aren't added to `Nat`, the `Nat` class describes singleton types whose values/types are inductively defined natural numbers. Note that, `Zero` is the only inhabitant of `Z` but the type `S Int`, for example, has many inhabitants (it is not a singleton); the `Nat` class restricts the parameter of `S` to singleton types. Intuitively, any data type with more than one data constructor is not a singleton type.

Give the above, we can write the dependently-typed successor function:

```
succ :: Nat n => n -> (S n)
succ n = Succ n
```

In the type signature, the type variable `n` can be seen as a value since the `Nat n` constraint restricts `n` to the class of singleton types representing natural numbers. The return type of the `succ` then *depends* on this value, where `S` is parameterised by the value `n`.

Any value that can be inductively defined can be given a unique singleton type representation.

A useful technique is to use GADTs to parameterise non-singleton types with singleton types (i.e. with values). This can be used, for example, to give a type-level representation of the shape of an inductively defined data type. The classic example is a sized-list:

```
data List n a where
   Nil :: List Z a 
   Cons :: Nat n => a -> List n a -> List (S n) a
```

Here the natural number singleton types parameterise the list-type by its length.

Thinking in terms of the polymorphic lambda calculus, `succ` above takes two arguments, the type `n` and then a value parameter of type `n`. Thus, singleton types here provides a kind of [Π-type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_type_theory#.CE.A0-types), where `succ :: Πn:Nat . n -> S(n)` where the argument to `succ` in Haskell provides both the dependent product parameter `n:Nat` (passed as the type parameter) and then the argument value.

Comment: Good answer, but mentioning the newer `DataKinds` stuff might be helpful as well. Also, re: type classes, with MPTCs and fundeps type classes are also used for ad hoc types-depending-on-types (as opposed to parametric type constructors). So there is a tenuous connection there, if only by accidental circumstance.

Comment: Yes, there is much to also say about `DataKinds` and MPCTs/fundeps. I tried to keep this brief. There must be a nice tutorial on all these techniques somewhere in one place?

Comment: GHC seems to acquire new extensions faster than extensions acquire detailed tutorials... anyway, I brought up `DataKinds` because of the fancier singleton stuff accompanying it, and because it's intended to replace stuff like your example with a `Nat` class. MPTCs and fundeps are a whole different can of worms.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer! Things are much clearer now :)