# How to define a function with different types of input and output?

Tags: haskell

I tried the following code:

```haskell
data InputType = NumType Int Int | StrType String String
data OutputType = Either Int String
add' :: InputType -> InputType -> OutputType
add' (NumType a b) = a + b
add' (StrType a b) = a ++ b
```

But failed :(

Comment: If this is not just an exercise, note that your specific problem can be solved with the [`Monoid`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html) class: for instance, you can try, in GHCi, `import Data.Monoid` followed by `"foo" <> "bar"` and `Sum 2 <> Sum 3`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your declaration of `OutputType` does not specify that it can be either an `Int` or a `String`; rather, you have created a new *pair* that requires both an `Int` *and* a `String`. Your data constuctor `Either` just happens to have the same name as the *type* constructor `Either`.

I think you meant

```
type OutputType = Either Int String
```

in which case you can then define your function if you use the correct constructors

```
add' :: InputType -> OutputType
add' (NumType a b) = Left (a + b)
add' (StrType a b) = Right (a ++ b)
```

Comment: `• Couldn't match expected type ‘InputType -> OutputType’
                  with actual type ‘Either Int b0’
    • Possible cause: ‘Left’ is applied to too many arguments
      In the expression: Left (a + b)
      In an equation for ‘add'’: add' (NumType a b) = Left (a + b)`

Comment: @gongqj The problem is the signature you gave `add'`. For the function you wrote it should be `add' :: InputType -> OutputType`

Comment: Oh, I forgot to change the signature before. Thanks for you reply. Now, the definition is ok, but still failed when to call `add' $ NumType 1 2`  _**Data constructor not in scope: NumInput :: Integer -> Integer -> InputType**_

Comment: It looks like you typed `NumInput` instead of `NumType`.

Comment: Sorry, I was just refactoring the type name, and then see your reply, so there is a typo.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a GADT to represent at the value level the type of the input you're getting:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

module Add where

data SType a where
  SString :: SType String
  SInt    :: SType Int

add :: SType a -> a -> a -> a
add SString = (++)
add SInt    = (+)
```

I called the GADT `SType` because it's a [singleton type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017294/singleton-types-in-haskell).